# background color of UILabel is become clear after reload Table

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am working in UiTableViewController and and I created Custom cell with XIB. I just set black color to one label. Hear I am attached three image for better explanation.

[image: first image for initial look of background color (B.G) of UILabel]

at the time of selection in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I change it black to blue.

[image]

the main problem is when i just scroll my table then the background color of that label become clear.

[image]

In cellForRowAtIndexpath method, I just add this condition,

```
if (inboxSelcted == 1) { 
  cell.lblNoOfIndexItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
} else { 
  cell.lblNoOfIndexItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code for cellForRowAtIndexpath?

Comment: Can you edit with `cellForRow atindexPath` function?

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexpath method, I just add this condition, 

 if (inboxSelcted == 1)
            {
                cell.lblNoOfIndexItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.lblNoOfIndexItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }

Comment: @PALAKiOSDeveloper Update code in your question

Comment: Can you check the outer scope of this condition check? You may have some default behaviour from the dequeued cell (basically from IB-UI). If that is the case you can set any one colour to the label right after the cell init line.

Comment: Your condition was wrong change it to if (indexPath.row == inboxSelcted ) {
// here your blue color  } else { // here your black color }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **cellForRowAtIndexpath** method, try like this as per your screenshot inbox index is 2. So,

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) { 
 cell.lblNoOfIndexItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
} else { 
 cell.lblNoOfIndexItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
}
```

And in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method,

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) { 
 inboxSelcted = indexPath.row; 
}
```

try like this and let me know, does it work!

Comment: Thx Antony Raphel. Only I like to add i just change in your answer '3' to '2' and its works.. Thx again Sir.